# Does scaling appear on a phase boundary/first order phase transitions, or it is only reserved to critical points?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena

In statistical mechanics people talk about scaling laws and critical phenomenon, and one of the textbook examples brought up is the liquid-gas critical point. But in contexts of Superconductivity and other fields I see that $T_c$ is a critical temperature where transition occurs (which is different from critical point I think because there could be a $T_c$ for first order transitions as well--please correct me if I'm wrong).

Going back to the phase diagram of solid-liquid-gas, we see that there are phase boundaries (first order transition lines) and then there is a critical point (the liquid-gas critical point). Do we see scaling emerge at the first order phase transitions, in say solid-liquid line? Can all phase transitions be characterized by scaling?

Comment: At first order phase transitions, the correlation length remains finite (and is typically of the same order of magnitude as the lattice spacing), so there is no emergence of scale invariance and consequently no scaling laws.

Comment: Thank you! Just a follow up, Why is the correlation length finite in a first order phase transition?